# Gradle refresh in IntelliJ changes language level of modules

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-15

I have a Gradle project that consists of an Android library module and a plain old Java module. (The Android library module has a dependency on the plain Java module.)

In the `build.gradle` file of the Android library module I have this:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

And in the `build.gradle` file of the plain old Java module I have this:

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
    targetCompatibility = "1.8"
}
```

When I hit the Gradle refresh button in IntelliJ IDEA 15, the language level for the Android module is set to Java 8 (as I'd expect) but the language level of the Java module is set to Java 1.6. **Why is this and is there any way for IntelliJ to set the language level of the Java module to Java 8 on a refresh instead?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` if you are using the new `Jack` compiler or the `Retrolambda` plugin for `Gradle`.

So you should be using:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

As far as the Intellij/Android Studio language settings goes:

1. File -> Project Structure:

[image]

2. You should set the project language settings accordingly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on dropping the Java version for the Android module down to `1.7`. (I thought I could compile with Java 1.8 as long as I didn't use the Java 1.8 language features.) I dropped the Java version in the plain old Java module to `1.7` also and now IntelliJ sets the `Project Language Level` to `8` and the `Language level` of both modules in the project to `7` automatically every time I do a fresh. Strange why the project level and module level values are different but it works for me so I'll leave it be for now.